# How to get the bit rate of streaming video?

Tags: java, android, streaming

i've integrated a packet sniffer in my streaming video software. Can i get the bit rate this way:

```
 (total size of all RTP packets - their headers) / 
                                       measure time(For example: 1 min ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

## bitrate = number of bits sent over a period of time

So, yeah, your algorithm is fine.  The wikipedia article on [bit-rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate) is a fairly lengthly read but may be of interest.  Having done this myself, I have a couple of implementation notes for you:

- Don't forget to do the byte/bit conversion!
- A more accurate rate will be measured over a longer period of time.  This is especially true with mobile devices which can see a much more "bursty" network connection that you may expect.
- The headers aren't going to be that much, especially with video. It may not be worth the effort